# VBA disable web browser sound

Tags: vba, audio, browser

I'm making an application which uses the webbrowser (in the background) to retrieve some information from a certain website. This website plays sound, resulting in users hearing sound from "nowhere" as they do not see the browser.

So I was wondering, is it possible to mute sounds coming from the browser and/or mute click sounds?

Comment: Use an XMLHTTPRequest instead of the IE object.

Answer (score 1):

This will click the mute button and mute ALL sound

```
Option Explicit
Private Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32" ( _
  ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, _
   ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Long)

    Const VK_VOLUME_MUTE = &HAD 'Windows 2000/XP: Volume Mute key

Sub mute()
keybd_event VK_VOLUME_MUTE, 0, 1, 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting. You might want to add whether (or how) to unmute.

Comment: its the same macro, all this macro does i toggle the mute button

Comment: That's what I thought, but wanted to be sure.